# UWP Text Styles?

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

If I want to add a drop shadow or glow effect to text in a button or textbox, is there any way to do that short of replacing the text with an image?

Also, Microsoft warns on their 'Guidelines for fonts' page, "UWP apps that will available on mobile devices should never use fonts for UI content other than fonts in this list." That list is pretty short. Does that mean that I can't or shouldn't use a custom font, even if I include it in the package, rather than as a download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a good way to apply effects to XAML content, WinRT also currently lacks a way to render XAML elements to a bitmap so you are mainly left with methods where you don't use XAML.

Make sure the glow is necessary and you have reviewed the guidelines. And you already did, so my best suggestion would be to not use it. If your sure you need it here are a few suggestions:

For simple cases you may be able to use gradients or duplicated geometry to get a glow affect.

- Bundle graphics with the glow already applied with your app, this obviously wouldn't work for completely dynamic shapes but you could do it for text similar to my answer here.
- Use Direct2D instead of XAML and use Direct2D effects (SharpDX offers bindings for Direct2D)
- If you need to apply a glow to a bitmap you could use a WriteableBitmap and apply the glow yourself. (WriteableBitmapEX could be useful)
- In classic WinRT apps, you could use HTML and CSS instead of XAML, possibly hosted in a WebView or for the whole app.

My suggestion is still to not use it and follow the guidelines. The app-certification process is usually strict on this, so if you plan to publish the app in the Store in the future; I would suggest you save your time and not use text-effects.

The last method would be to edit the control itself in Visual Blend and then create a copy of the resource, but that is a nasty way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer Tobias. Let me make sure that I understand what your saying. If I have a button with a number 1 on it, and I want to create various themes for my app, I cannot style the button's text using xaml, but I could use one of the methods you describe above, including using a photo shopped graphic, but Microsoft recommends against theming your app?

Comment: You could indeed style them with different styles, but NOT with text effects that goes against the strict guidelines I'm sorry to tell you. You could indeed use a photo as a button instead which is the better option but the different button-element states like :active :hover :focus :visited etc would be hard to manage.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.